# subtract instruction in processors

Tags: processor, cpu-architecture

Why should a processor implement a subtract instruction ? Why cant the compilers change subtraction to 2-s complement additions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because if every subtraction had to be two instructions (negate and add) then you'd waste a lot of memory traffic (because code would become larger), cache space (because code would be larger), and instruction decode time (because there would be more instructions to decode), for a tiny gain in CPU simplicity. Totally not worth it.

Comment: Note: If the compiler knows the CPU does add or subtract faster, and the code uses a constant for either operand, the CPU may perform the negation of the constant for you and switch the operand. So `x = y - 5` might be converted to assembly equivalent to `x = y + -5` if the CPU is better at addition than subtraction. But yeah, for the general case, changing `x = y - z` to `x = y + (-z)` would at best be equivalent speed, and at worst suffer all the problems mentioned in this answer, for trivial gain (the CPU could still choose to perform subtract as a negate followed by add after all).

Answer (score 0):

Addition and subtraction are used enough that it makes sense to build it in. It is a trade off between having more native instructions which require less CPU cycles to faster CPU cycles (more cycles / second).